# Solutions of a recursive equation.

Tags: calculus, integration, recursion

I was reading "Inside Interesting Integrals" by Paul J. Nahin. In Section 2.3, this integral has been solved. $$I_n(\alpha)=\int_0^\pi{\dfrac{\cos(n\theta)-\cos(n\alpha)}{\cos\theta-\cos\alpha}}d\theta$$
Using some manipulations, this recursive equation was obtained. $$I_{n+1}(\alpha)-2\cos\alpha I_n(\alpha)+I_{n-1}(\alpha)=0$$
The author has directly used the solutions of this equation.

> It is well-known that such a so-called recursive equation has solutions of the
> form $I_n=Ce^{sn}$ where $C$ and $s$ are constants.

I want to know how this solution is derived.
Also, we obtain $s=\pm i\alpha$ by putting the solution in the equation. Using this, it is stated that $I_n(\alpha)=C_1e^{in\alpha}+C_2e^{-in\alpha}$. But, shouldn't it be just $I_n(\alpha)=Ce^{\pm in\alpha}$?

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients#Order_2).

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I couldn't really comprehend anything of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given is a recurrence relation, of the form $a_n = Aa_{n-1} + Ba_{n-2}$ which is an example of a recurrence relation of second order with constant coefficients . In your case $A = 2\cos\alpha$ and $B = -1$. Essentially the solutions to recurrence relations and differential equations first follow by using educated guesses.

As for why we add the two, the solution we represent is the *general* solution, i.e. since the two are indeed solutions for the recurrence relation, any linear combination

$$ C_1 e^{ina} + C_2 e^{-ina}$$

of the two will be a valid solution for our relation. However, if we are given initial conditions, then we can just use the conditions to either find the relation between $C1$ and $C2$ (if 1 conditions) or determine the coefficients themselves (if 2 conditions given).

Comment: So, the solution $Ce^{sn}$ was just found by guessing? It was not found in any way?

Comment: Not really, but in this case the solution of a second order recurrence relation is relatively well known. If you are not convinced you may try _working backwards_ assume that $a_n = r_1^{n-1} + r_2^{n-2} + k$ and try to obtain a recurrence relation from this.